# Can a C++ program connect to a database over HTML/XML?

Tags: c++, web-services

This is more of a technical question;  I don't have any code to offer as I've only begun experimenting with basic output in CPP, and I currently see this as my most difficult task.

In a desktop application I'm coding, I am trying to allow users to sign into their online account they have with my web app, but obviously it would wouldn't make sense to include the same DB connection I use for hosting my site...

Is there a way I can send JUST username and password values over POST in cpp and use these values to achieve desired functionality in PHP?

Hopefully my question makes sense; I'm simply wondering how one would interact with a web server over CPP (without a direct db connection...)

Comment: Use a HTTP library. There are many to choose from.

Comment: The idea itself isn't strange (well, except for the HTML part). but that does mean the Internet is already full of relevant information on this topic. Don't reinvent the wheel. then.(Such as sending a password over the Internet - we figured out that's a bad idea in the 20th century).

Comment: Sending a password over the internet?...  But what do you do everytime you log in to stackoverflow?